# Thumbnail URL from picture column in SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, thumbnail

I have a SharePoint List with a picture column and an image stored in there. The path to the full image is:

```
https://my-sharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/Sitename/SiteAssets/Lists/1dd174b6-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-621c1c8015ec/Arztpraxis-Empfang[1].jpg
```

After using the browser debug mode I found a ultra long and cryptic URL to the thumbnail image, which is not related to my SharePoint in any way. Seems like it's pointing to a BLOB.

Is there a way to reference to the thumbnail directly instead of displaying the full resolution image within the list?

My code so far:

```
{
  "elmType": "img",
  "style": {
    "display": "flex",
    "self-align": "center",
    "height": "100%",
    "z-index": "0"
  },
  "attributes": {
    "src": "[$PraxisFoto.serverRelativeUrl])"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the data type of column, [Image](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/) or Hyperlink/Picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an Image column from your use of properties in the format above. In this case, you can take advantage of the `thumbnailRenderer` included in Image columns:

```
{
  "elmType": "img",
  "attributes": {
    "src": "=@currentField.thumbnailRenderer.spItemUrl + '/thumbnails/0/c48x48/content?prefer=noredirect&cb=1&s=' + @currentField.thumbnailRenderer.sponsorToken"
  }
}
```

There are a number of samples that might be helpful to look at as well:

- [Image Lightbox](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/image-lightbox) - for image columns showing the above technique though I've removed the `closestavailablesize` portion of the querystring in the json above to ensure you actually get a scaled thumbnail
- [Generic Hyperlink Thumbnail](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/generic-hyperlink-thumbnail) - for use with Picture columns (though you can use the same technique with a URL to an image)
- [File Thumbnail](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/file-thumbnail) - Uses formattings `@thumbnail` magic string in document libraries

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!